# Armor of the Old Gods Bug--It Keeps Coming Back!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I finished the quest: [No One Escapes Cidhna Mine](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/No_One_Escapes_Cidhna_Mine) a while ago. I made the mistake of asking Aela to hold on to the [Armor of the Old Gods](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Armor_of_the_Old_Gods), which she promptly equipped, even though she already had the [Thieves Guild Armor](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Thieves_Guild_Armor) equipped (which has a better Armor rating-33 vs 24).

Now, she looks great when she wears it; kind of a Sheenah, Queen of the Jungle vibe.  However, even after I took the armor away from her and sold it three times, when I take my eyes off her and look back, there she is wearing the Armor of the Old Gods again. (We're married, so she may be going behind my back and buying the armor back from the vendor when I'm not looking.)

As much as it's cool to see her in her jungle garb, I'd much rather have her in armor that improves her carrying capacity and Armor rating rather than the one that improves Destruction spells (which she doesn't use).

Anyone else come up with this respawning armor bug?  Any solution or code or mod to fix this ridiculous situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I took Aela home and left her there in favor of Mjoll. When I came back to the house to pick her up a couple of weeks later, she was in her old armor (but still had the good stuff, the Thieves Guild Armor). After I checked her inventory (and found she still had the Armor of the Old Gods), I brought her along and ever since, she's only worn the Thieves Guild Armor.

I guess having her cool her jets for a couple of weeks (days?) was enough to have her listen to me.